# Use of chlorohexidine gluconate for disinfection and minimisation of bacteria growth

Tags: dermatology

Chlorohexidine gluconate (topical/wash-off), is a semi-essential disinfectant in domestic environments and furthermore in the maintenance and minimisation of bacterial growth in medical conditions that thrive off their presence. For example, follicular infections such as folliculitus (gram-negative or Gram-positive).

Could however, the long-term use (6 months +) of Chlorohexidine Gluconate yield negative effects when used as a skin disinfectant-wash for the face? E.g. dermatologically.